# Getting feedback from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel

I have a simple webform which has two fields that accepts number values. What I would like to do is compare the values in each field and, if they aren't valid, display a message to the user.

I'm currently using the ValidationAttribute in my viewmodel for this and the method 'isValid', where true is returned if the values are valid and false if they're not but I'm unsure how to capture the true/false return and make use of it. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class AlertValuesCheck : ValidationAttribute
{
    private static double minAlert;
    private static double maxAlert;

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (maxAlert == 0)
            maxAlert = (double)value;
        else
            minAlert = (double)value;

        if (maxAlert < minAlert)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere...

```
[Display(Name = "Max Alert Boundary")]
[AlertValuesCheck]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required!")]
public Nullable<double> MaxAlertBoundary { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Min Alert Boundary")]
[AlertValuesCheck]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required!")]
public Nullable<double> MinAlertBoundary { get; set; }
```

Ideally I would like to have a message displayed like [Required(ErrorMessage)] does. Is this possible? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the Fluent Validation library?

Comment: Just taken a look at it - looks very promising

Comment: I like it because it takes the validation logic out of the view models and makes it more easily testable. It's no longer a concern of the view model.

Answer (score 1):

You already have `ErrorMessage` property on your `AlertValuesCheck` as it extends [ValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

So you can just go with :

```
[AlertValuesCheck(ErrorMessage = "Your error message !!")]
```

Comment: This is exactly along the lines of what I was after however my program ignores this even after changing both returns to false (my error message wasn't shown). Do you think I could be missing something else in this?